# How to redirect a folder to home page using web config file?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have a specific folder in my root where I want that url to be redirected to homepage when someone is visiting that url .
I want to know how it should be done in web config file .

www.domainname.com/folder/ should be redirected to www.domainname.com

Comment: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpRedirect

Comment: did you tried ***urlMappings*** ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but you will try this:

```
<system.web><urlMappings>
  <add url="www.domainname.com" mappedUrl="www.domainname.com/folder/"/>
</urlMappings></system.web>
```

Comment: Wanted to mention you can do this for relative folders as well, not just full domain names, by doing stuff like url="~/abc" mappedUrl ="~/someotherplace/abc"

Comment: `www.domainname.com/folder/ any/anynotexits` can be redirect to *www.domainname.com* ?